Can a Tankless Heater be Harmed by a Shutoff?
I have a mobile home in a park which I come to every weekend and during the week when I'm not here I shut the main water off will this hurt my tankless heater turning the water supply off? We always shut the water off so there's no problem with a leak while we're not here.

This should be OK. But to play it safe, I would recommend shutting off power (electric and/or gas) to the water heater. While a tankless water heater shouldn't turn on if there is no water flowing, and very little water can flow if the input is closed, turning off power will 100% avoid any possible problem.
